# How do I change the timezone of a user in Weavy?

Tags: timezone, weavy

Changing the timezone of a user to your local one is quite essential because it lessens the complexity of understanding the local time of the user with respect to your timezone. While using the built-in weavy.fetch() function, which calls the web API endpoints of the server, the server always returns data with respect to the UTC timezone. Hence, to lessen the complexity, we need to convert the dates and times to our preferred timezone. So, I would like to ask how can we convert the timezone according to our convenience.

I tried searching the weavy docs regarding the timezone conversion, but it only states to convert the dates and times to our preferred timezones but not the process. Hence, declaring the way of conversion will be highly beneficial.